# Proof of Infinite Sets and Natural Numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If a set is an infinite set, is it the case that we can always find a 1-to-1 fxn from the said infinite set to the set of natural numbers N = {1,2,3}?

I know that if the infinite set is such that set N is a proper subset of it (such as set Z of integers), then there must be a 1-to-1 correspondence. But what if otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

No, such a function does not necessarily exist.

The set of natural numbers $\mathbb N$ is a proper subset of the real numbers $\mathbb R$, but there is no one-to-one function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb N$. The proof is quite famous and is known as "Cantor's diagonal argument."

This examples also shows that your assumption in the second paragraph is incorrect.